# django-rest-auth logout failure

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-auth for authentication. Login and Registration is working fine, however logout method gives me an error. I had used this same library in previous projects but never faced this issue, so I am not sure if anything has changed since then.

[image]

It asks me to fill in some data, which was not the case before.

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),

}

SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True was missing in settings.py and it allowed logout, however I am not sure what to do about POST

Comment: Are you still getting the 405 error if you POST to logout?

Comment: Well I was trying out in browsable api, and did not post at all saying fill the fields.